# What is this node.js / v8 FATAL error?

Tags: node.js, v8, fatal-error, node-inspector, nodemon

I run a node app and I use grunt to control my workflow.

I just get this error that I never got before:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/deoptimizer.cc, line 2764
# CHECK(result == fixed_size + (stack_slots * kPointerSize) + outgoing_size) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

 1: V8_Fatal
 2: v8::internal::Deoptimizer::Deoptimizer(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::JSFunction*, v8::internal::Deoptimizer::BailoutType, unsigned int, unsigned char*, int, v8::internal::Code*)
 3: v8::internal::Deoptimizer::DebuggerInspectableFrame(v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*, int, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 4: v8::internal::FrameInspector::FrameInspector(v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*, int, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 5: v8::internal::Runtime_GetFrameDetails(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 6: ??
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Note that I ran `node v0.12.7` + `grunt` + `nodemon` + `node-inspector` this time.

I re-run the script and now this works fine.

From where it could be from ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is from `node-inspector`, you're trying to get debug information from Node. But you could have hit a possible undiscovered bug or a simple unrelated system failure.